# Can't close Bootstrap 3 modal window after clicking submit (vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, forms, bootstrap-modal, typescript

I'm new to all of this so please bear with me...

I have a Bootstrap 3 modal window that opens up with a few form fields in it. I've managed to append the form fields to the DOM after you click `Submit New Appointment`. Buuut I can't seem to figure out how to close the modal window after the fields have been appended to the DOM. I'm hoping to achieve this by writing some good ole vanilla JavaScript. (Unfortunately I cannot use any jQuery.)

I have included the vanilla JavaScript code below. (It basically creates an appointment card from the info inputed from the form thats in the modal and then it gets displayed as a card into the DOM.)

Thanks for taking a look!

```js
var form = document.getElementById('addForm');

// element to append the new carousel item to

var itemList = document.querySelector('.carousel-inner');

// form submit event

form.addEventListener('submit', addItem);

// form delete event

itemList.addEventListener('click', removeItem);

// add item Function

function addItem(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  // get input value in the modal

  var newItem = document.getElementById('item').value;

  var newItemTwo = document.getElementById('time').value;

  var newItemThree = document.getElementById('name-of-client').value;

  var newItemFour = document.getElementById('phone-number-client').value;

  var newItemFive = document.getElementById('acces-notes').value;

  // create a new li element with the text grab from above

  var li = document.createElement('li');
  /**
   * Set the correct class name for the carousel to work
   */
  // li.className = 'list-group-item';
  li.className = 'item';
  li.style.maxWidth = '95%';
  li.style.border = 'solid 1px #d3d3d3';
  li.style.padding = '10px';
  li.style.height = '150px';
  li.style.marginRight = '12%';
  li.style.marginLeft = '12%';
  li.style.fontWeight = '500';
  li.style.fontSize = '14px';

  // console.log(li)

  // create a new p element with the text grab from above

  var pOne = document.createElement('p');
  pOne.className = 'items';
  pOne.style.fontSize = '12px';
  pOne.style.fontWeight = '400';
  pOne.style.marginTop = '5px';

  var pTwo = document.createElement('p');
  pTwo.className = 'items';
  pTwo.style.fontSize = '12px';
  pTwo.style.fontWeight = '200';

  console.log(pTwo)

  var pThree = document.createElement('p');
  pThree.className = 'items';
  pThree.style.fontSize = '12px';
  pThree.style.fontWeight = '200';
  console.log(pThree)

  var pFour = document.createElement('p');
  pFour.className = 'items';
  pFour.style.fontSize = '12px';
  pFour.style.fontWeight = '200';
  console.log(pFour)

  // add text node with input value

  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newItem));

  pOne.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newItemTwo));

  pTwo.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newItemThree));

  pThree.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newItemFour));

  pFour.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newItemFive));

  // create delete BUTTON
  var deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
  deleteBtn.style.width = '50px';
  deleteBtn.style.float = 'right';
  deleteBtn.style.height = '50px';
  deleteBtn.style.borderRadius = '50%'
  deleteBtn.style.border = 'solid 1px red';
  deleteBtn.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  deleteBtn.style.color = 'red';

  // add the classes to the delete BUTTON

  deleteBtn.className = "btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete";

  // append the text node

  deleteBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('X'));

  // append delete button into the LI

  li.appendChild(deleteBtn);

  // append li to list.

  /**
   * insert the new element at the beginning of the itemList element, not at the end
   */
  // itemList.appendChild(li);
  itemList.insertBefore(li, itemList.firstChild);

  // append p elements into LI; (not sure if this is the best way but its working)
  li.appendChild(pOne);
  li.appendChild(pTwo);
  li.appendChild(pThree);
  li.appendChild(pFour);
  li.appendChild(pFive);

}

// remove item function

function removeItem(e) {

  console.log(e.target)

  if (e.target.classList.contains('delete')) {

    if (confirm('Are you sure bro?')) {

      var li = document.querySelector('.item.active');

      itemList.removeChild(li);

      document.querySelector('.item').classList.add('active')

    }

  }

}
```

[Image of the modal from Bootstrap 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFKc2.png)

Comment: Have you looked at [Bootstraps documentation on how to close the modal with javascript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-methods)?

Comment: Secondly, Bootstrap 3.3.7 JS components **require** jQuery so.... whats your plan now taking that into consideration?

Comment: If you want help, you need to provide your HTML as well.  There are ways to create a modal and close it without Bootstrap/jQuery, but Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.